# postgresql SSL unable to connect

Tags: database, postgresql, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am trying to connect an application named thingsboard with a postgresql DB both running on Google Cloud Engine.
I have the following files provided by GCE when I set up the DB as allow only SSL connections:

```
client-cert.pem client-key.pem server-ca.pem
```

This is where the connection to the DB is set up. I tried with a the client-key.pem as client-key.pem, client-key.key, client-key.pk8 (with and without passphrase, when added passphrase I added the field "sslpassword=MYKEY"

```
url: "${SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL:jdbc:postgresql://DATABASEIP:5432/thingsboard?sslmode=verify-ca&sslrootcert=/etc/thingsboard/conf/keystore/server-ca.pem&sslcert=/etc/thingsboard/conf/keystore/client-cert.pem&sslkey=/etc/thingsboard/conf/keystore/client-key.pk8}"
username: "${SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME:MYDBUSERNAME}"
password: "${SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD:MYDBPASSWORD}"
```

I am getting the following error

```
2019-01-16 18:55:32,866 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool - Unable to create initial connections of pool.
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Could not read SSL key file /etc/thingsboard/conf/keystore/client-key.pk8.
```

Comment: A file or directory permission problem?

Comment: Files do exist, and previously I was using "classpath:keystore/server-ca.pem" instead of the complete path and I was getting an error regarding that, now that I changed all of them that problem is not happening anymore. But it could be, how can I check that?

Comment: Use `su` or `sudo` to become the OS user under which the Java code is running and try to `cat` the file.

Comment: I cannot open the file with cat without using sudo, it is very likely that the application cannot open it to, since I created it with openssl. How do I remove the restriction from this file?

Comment: What is `ls -ld` for the file and all direcrories in its path? Add that to the question rather than as a comment. Maybe you can put the file in a place with less restrictive permissions. What type of file is it anyway?

Comment: -rw------- 1 root root 1217 Jan 16 18:54 client-key.pk8

Comment: `chmod o+r /etc/thingsboard/conf/keystore/client-key.pk8`

Comment: This solved my issue, I am able to connect using SSL. Thanks